# How to use other Angular11 service inside an ngrx/Store reducer as an initial state?

Tags: angular, redux, dependency-injection, ngrx

New to reducers and effects. Basically, I have this reducer:

```
        const realColumnsReducer = createReducer<ColumnsState>(
          toData(AssetsColumns.columnsConfig),//here the service i need to use as a initial state
          on(setColumns, (state, action) => toData(action.columns)),
          on(setSelectedColumns, (state, action) =>
            toData(
              action.columns.map(x => ({
                ...x,
                enabled: true
              }))
            )
          )
```

here the part of  ijectble service i need to use

```
          columnsConfig: StatefulColumn[] = [
            {
              column: assetCategoryColumn,
              enabled: true
            },
         {
              column: assetCodeColumn,
              enabled: true
            }
        ].map((x, index) => ({ ...x, index, width: columnMinWidthPx } as StatefulColumn));
```

And here the effect that i have

```
    @Effect()
      applyCompanyPreferences = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(applyCompanyPreferences.request),
        switchMap(() => this.store.select(currentIdentity).pipe(onlyTruthy(), take(1))),
        switchMap(identity => from(loadCompanyPreferencesFromIndexedDb(identity))),
        map(x =>
          x
            ? x.columns.map(z => ({ ...this.assetsColumns.columnsConfig[z.index], ...z } as StatefulColumn))
            : this.assetsColumns.columnsConfig
        ),
        mergeMap(x => [setColumns({ columns: x }), applyCompanyPreferences.success({ request: undefined })]),
```

how can i use my service as a initial state?

Comment: Without understanding your code and business logic, i suggest that you should have a look on the official documentation of ngrx here `https://ngrx.io/guide/store`. As you can see on the first picture of the ngrx/redux flow you should only call your services from `effects` and never from your `reducers`. So in your case I would suggest something like making two actions: `fetchData` and `fetchDataSuccess` so that you can call your service on `fetchDataSuccess` action in your effect that will then change the state in the reducer. I hipe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you would like to employ the service to update the state on the first time.
Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#oniniteffects.

Besides this, the combination of switchMap and store.select is not correct. The last example in this page https://ngrx.io/guide/effects can give you an idea of how to do thing right.